# PhalconPHP - redirect in initialize()

Tags: php, phalcon

In my project I've created AjaxController which operated ajax requests. 
I'd like to user which enter to url used by ajax get 404 error. 
In AjaxController.php I have:

```
public function initialize() {
    if (!$this->request->isAjax()) {
        return $this->response->redirect('error/show404');
    }
}
```

(Of course I have ErrorController with show404Action)

It doesn't work. When i enter to example.com/ajax in browser I get content from IndexAction in AjaxController. How to repair it?

Comment: Maybe you could use a middleware for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try to do the same in `beforeExecuteRoute()`. Phalcon's `initialize()` is designed, as its name says, to initialize things. You can dispatch there using dispatcher, but should not redirect.

You can check part of documentation [here](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html#dispatch-loop-events). Column "can stop operation?" says if it is possible to return response object to complete request or `false` to stop evaluate to other methods and compile view.

One precious to know thing is that `beforeExecuteRoute()` executes every time before action is called, so may fire couple of times in case you are forwarding between your actions.

```
public function beforeExecuteRoute(Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher)
{
    if (!$this->request->isAjax()) {
        return $this->response->redirect('error/show404');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend forwarding user to 404 page via Dispatcher. This way the URL will remain and you will do everything according to SEO rules.

```
public function initialize() {
    if (!$this->request->isAjax()) {
        $this->dispatcher->forward(['controller' => 'error', 'action' => 'show404']);
    }
}
```

Also it's not a good idea to make redirects in initialize. More info from Phalcon here: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/3216/redirect-initialize-beforeexecuteroute-redirect-to-initalize-and

Adding my 404 method in case someone needs it. It demonstrates correct header handling (again for SEO purposes)

```
// 404
public function error404Action()
{
    $this->response->setStatusCode(404, 'Not Found');
    $this->view->pick(['templates/error-404']);
    $this->response->send();
}
```

Comment: I got warning - forward is void function.

Comment: My bad. Updated my answer above. Copied your code and forgot to remove return. Sorry :)

Comment: Ok, warning disappeared, but i still get content from IndexAction. There is no  forwarding to 404 page :(

Comment: Can you read the section Initializing Controllers here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/controllers.html#initializing-controllers and make sure you meet the requirements for using initialize() ?

Comment: If i var_dump something before forward() i see it.